# At which point does an ML model pick up biases in datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, bias

I am currently examining bias in NLP datasets such as [CommonsenseQA](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.00937.pdf). I am looking for a reference where researchers possibly claim *at which point*, i.e., how biased a dataset must be, in order for an ML model to pick it up. Is anyone aware of work going in this direction? I cannot find anything.

Comment: It starts at one data point. (What does it even mean to say “how biased” the data is? There’s a good quote from E.B. White, oddly enough, about how all data are biased.)

Comment: What does data bias mean here? Maybe read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff